# What is this tall tree with needle-like leaves?

Tags: identification, trees

Somebody saw this tree in a park (in Galicia, in northwestern Spain) and asked me to try and identify it. Here are 3 photos of the tree (click on each to enlarge):

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: also do you see any cones... and how many needles per bunch?

Comment: A pine, possibly a white pine, but hard to say without a closeup of the needles and it's location

Comment: I don't remember seeing any cones, either in the tree or in the floor, and I don't have any more info about the needles that it's not on the picture. I'm sorry I don't have more details. Anyway, I was searching and the leaves looked similar, could it be _Cedrus deodara_?

Comment: Pinus radiata (Monterey Pine)?

Comment: @EdStaub: I don't think so. Look at the needles.

Comment: Deciduous? Maybe a Larix or even Pseudolarix amabilis. The Cedrus deodara seems like a good guess also though it seems very light green.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going with [*Cedrus deodara*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedrus_deodara) of some variety too — the drooping tips of the branches indicate that.